# Quartz.net 2.2.4 Unable to Bind Schedular to remoting Error in Quartz.net windows service

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-services, quartz.net

Hi I trying to install Quartz Scheduler as a windows Service, for purpose of using it in my application.

I followed this example to do it 
[Install Quartz.net as windows service](http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2012/11/16/install-quartz.net-as-a-windows-service-and-test-installation.aspx)

Installation is successful, But getting some error in 
Step 3 : "quartz.server.exe -i" ,  This gives error in command so i used
        only  "quartz.server.exe" .
But again getting some error

Error:    " Quartz.Server.QuartzServer.Initialize - Server initialization failed : Unable to bind scheduler to remoting".

I am using quartz.net version 2.2.4 , Please Suggest to what to do I am totally stuck now. 
Can't Post Image of the error because of less Repo Points. Plz Help me .

Comment: Old question but relevant in my world. What did you ever do about it?

Comment: I don't remember exactly, as it's almost a decade now, But what I could recall is using a different lower version i guess  Quartz version 2.2.3 worked in my case .